# How to set or change the 2.2 GiB size of AWS instance-store backed root volume?

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've just launched an AWS EC2 `r3.large` instance with Ubuntu. `r3.large` has `32GB` SSD for instance store with it. My problem is that the size of the root volumne `/dev/xvda` is too small and I can't find an effective way to use all `32GB` in my instance-store backed EC2 instance.

1. If I don't Add Storage when [Launching an Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/launching-instance.html), I get an `/dev/xvda` of `10 GB`, which I understand is the maximum possible for instance-store root volumes.
2. If I do Add Storage when [Launching an Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/launching-instance.html), I get an even smaller `/dev/xvda` of only `2.2 GB` as shown by `sudo fdisk -l` below.

> Disk /dev/xvda: 2.2 GiB, 2361393152 bytes, 4612096 sectors
>       Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>       Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>       I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>       Disklabel type: dos
>       Disk identifier: 0xef20d59b
>
> ```
> Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
> /dev/xvda1 *     2048 4610047 4608000  2.2G 83 Linux
>
>
> Disk /dev/xvdb: 30 GiB, 32212254720 bytes, 62914560 sectors
> Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
> I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
> ```

My questions are:

1. How can I get an `10GB` root and use the rest of the instance store for `/dev/xvdb` ?  (instead of having a tiny root volume and everything else in `/dev/xvdb`)
2. Is there a way to use the space in `/dev/xvdb` seamlessly in the root volume?

-- UPDATE --

The output of `lsblk` is:

```
$ sudo lsblk 
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  2.2G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0  2.2G  0 part /
xvdb    202:16   0   30G  0 disk
```

Also, now I tried to launch new instances *without* specifying any additional storage (i.e. leaving it as the default), but I can't even get back the 10GB `/dev/xvda`. EC2 somehow consistently create the `2.2G` root, which isn't going to hold the packages I'm going to install.

Comment: What does `lsblk` show?  (edit into question, please)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Please see the update for `lsblk`.

Comment: I would be inclined to try something like [UnionFS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS) -- create a separate filesystem on that second (virtual) block device and merge it into your root filesystem.  Since they presented to the kernel as two devices, I don't see an obvious way to do it at a lower level.

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/add-instance-store-volumes.html

> For instances with an instance store volume for the root volume, the size of this volume varies by AMI, but the maximum size is 10 GB.